# Google chrome on android zooms page out on: open off canvas menu

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

have created a quick test off canvas menu in zurb foundation, works great except: On every other browser, than chrome (both ios and android) tested: (http://prntscr.com/obpii6) it looks like it should.

But in chrome when you "toggle" the "off canvas menu" then the menu opens as it should but then jumps and zooms out (the text becomes way small) http://prntscr.com/obpkjb

Anyone have any clues as to what might cause this? I have never experienced anything like it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else who bump into this, and find this question in a search:
I found out that in chrome on mobile devices you can activate a force zoom activation, this option in the browser settings seemed to be the culprit. The option isn't activated by default.

So if you experience something like this check the following: goto > settings > Accessibility > Force enable zoom option, deaktivate this and see if this helps.

If someone know of a clean way to prevent this strange zoom out via html,css og js, do share :)